# Insert into a table based on flag values of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, case, flags

I have two tables

```
src (party_key,is_NRA,is_DOM,is_PEP)
```

and

```
dest(party_key,aml_type,aml_name)
```

What I want to do is -

```
If src.is_NRA = 1, then insert into dest values (src.party_key,'NRA','Is NRA')
If src.is_DOM = 1, then insert into dest values (src.party_key,'DOM','Is DOM')
.
.
```

One row in src table can have all 3 flags as '1'. In that case, I want to insert 3 separate rows in dest table.

How can I implement this in SQL?

Comment: I don't see any other way around other than using a cursor.

Comment: Insert select, simple as that

Comment: @Rahul No need for `CURSOR`. See my answer. Keep it simple.

Comment: Select from src where = condition. From selected, insert into dest. Does not look complicated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
INSERT INTO dest(party_key,aml_type,aml_name) 
SELECT src.party_key, 'NRA', 'Is NRA' FROM src WHERE src.is_NRA = 1;
INSERT INTO dest(party_key,aml_type,aml_name)
SELECT src.party_key, 'DOM', 'Is DOM' FROM src WHERE src.is_DOM = 1;
INSERT INTO dest(party_key,aml_type,aml_name)
SELECT src.party_key, 'PEP', 'Is PEP' FROM src WHERE src.is_PEP = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

INSERTing with three separate SELECTs may be fine for your purposes, but that's three separate table scans.  INSERTing with one table scan is possible if you UNPIVOT (reference:  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

```
INSERT INTO
    dest (
        party_key,
        aml_type,
        aml_name
    )
SELECT
    party_key,
    RIGHT([type], 3),
    'Is ' + RIGHT([type], 3)
FROM
    src
UNPIVOT (
    flag FOR [type] IN (
        is_NRA,
        is_DOM,
        is_PEP
    )
) unpvt
WHERE 
    flag = 1
```

Comment: I thought of something like that after reading the question. You don't need a subselect, though, `... FROM src UNPIVOT ...` would work just as well.

Comment: @Andriy M  Good point.  I inadvertently left that in from my initial fiddling.  I'll remove it to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?

```
   IF src.is_dom = 1 AND src.is_NRA = 1 AND src.is_PEP = 1,
   THEN
      INSERT INTO dest (party_key, aml_type, aml_name)
           VALUES (src.party_key, 'DOM', 'Is DOM'), (src.party_key,'NRA','Is NRA'), (src.party_key,'PEP','Is PEP')
```